# Скрипт для поиска файлов в каталоге, с последующей манипуляцией над найденными файлами

Tags: bash

Моя задача найти все файлы в заданном каталоге превосходящие по размеру N Мб, затем упаковать эти файлы в архив, удалить исходники и создать файлы с теми же именами.
Правильно ли будет работать тело цикла,т.е. записывать в переменную file один файл из index, затем удалять файл,заложенный в file,затем создавать такой же,но пустой ?
 Я бы мог запустить в системе, но опасаюсь удаления данных.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter path"
read path
echo "Enter size"
read size
index=$(find $path -type f -size +"$size"M)
find $path -type f -size +"$size"M | xargs tar -rvf archive.tar
for file in index
do
rm file
touch file
done
```